# Select 1 True, 1 False per group in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with ~1mil rows, and ~100k unique events.  There is 1 column `Won` which 1 row per event which is set to True, and each other row in the event has set as False.

i.e.,

```
Event ID  Runner ID  Won
 E1        R1        True
 E1        R2        False
 E1        R3        False
 E2        R4        True
 E2        R5        False
 E2        R6        False
```

and what I'd like to end up with is a balanced DataFrame, with only 1 winner, and only 1 non-winner per group.

i.e.,

```
Event ID  Runner ID  Won
 E1        R1        True
 E1        R3        False
 E2        R4        True
 E2        R5        False
```

I don't care which non-winner is selected per event, just so long as there's 1 winner, one non-winner.

With pandas, I've tried a few things, select the winners, and the non-winners,

```
_won = df.Won
winners = df[_won]

non_winners = df[~_won]
```

but each process I've seen, and tried for selecting 1 non-winner per race has been extremely slow - as in a few seconds per event (which is IMO unreasonable when you've 100k events).

One-shot with `group` and `apply`,

```
new_df = winners.append(
    non_winners
    .groupby('Event ID')
    .apply(lambda grp: grp.sample(1))
```

Iterating over groupby,

```
for event_id, grp in non_winners.groupby('Event ID'):
    winners.append(grp.sample(1))
```

Iterating over the event ids in winners,

```
event_ids = set(winners['Event ID'].drop_duplicates())
for event_id in event_ids:
    winners.append(
        non_winners[non_winners['Event ID'] == event_id].sample(1))
```

But each option seems to be incredibly slow when dealing with ~1mil and ~100k events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `head`.

```
df.groupby(['Event ID', 'Won']).head(1)

  Event ID Runner ID    Won
0       E1        R1   True
1       E1        R2  False
3       E2        R4   True
4       E2        R5  False
```

As long as you're not picky as to what is retained in the output since the output is balanced.

---

There's also `drop_duplicates`.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Event ID', 'Won'], keep='last') 
# or keep='first', it doesn't matter

  Event ID Runner ID    Won
0       E1        R1   True
2       E1        R3  False
3       E2        R4   True
5       E2        R6  False
```

And finally, if you want to implement shuffling, call `sample` beforehand:

```
(df.sample(frac=1)
   .sort_values(by=['Event ID'])
   .drop_duplicates(['Event ID', 'Won'])
)

  Event ID Runner ID    Won
2       E1        R3  False
0       E1        R1   True
4       E2        R5  False
3       E2        R4   True
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the multiple options.  I had actually used a variant of the drop_duplicates one, but for whatever reason I must have tripped over my own feet / got confused, and not continued that way.

Answer (score 0):

One option I've come up with that I'm happy enough with the speed is using a combination of shuffle and duplicated on the non-winners rows,

```
_won = df.Won
winners = df[_won]
_non_winners = shuffle(df[~_won])

non_winners = _non_winners[~_non_winners.duplicated('Event ID')]

new_df = winners.append(non_winners)
```

In the other options, it was taking something like a second per group, which was unsustainable for it running through that amount of groups, whereas this solution gives, for as far as I can see, the exact same result, but in about 10 seconds, compared to I don't know how long.

If you want more than 1 per grouping, it's fiddly but possible, you just do basically the same again,

```
...
_non_winners = shuffle(df[~_won])

dupeys = _non_winners.duplicated('Event ID')
new_df = pandas.concat([
    winners,
    _non_winners[~dupeys]])

_non_winners = _non_winners[dupeys]
new_df = pandas.concat([
    new_df,
    _non_winners[~_non_winners.duplicated('race_event_id')]])
```